# Django (DRF) fails silently

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have been working on a side project using django and django rest framework. There is even an active version running in the cloud currently without any issue. I wanted to make some minor changes on the code base but while using the django admin page it crashes silently. I haven't changed anything in the code until now.

```bash
[2022-08-31 13:39:10 +0200] [8801] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-08-31 13:39:10 +0200] [8801] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (8801)
[2022-08-31 13:39:10 +0200] [8801] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-08-31 13:39:10 +0200] [8802] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8802
[2022-08-31 13:39:18 +0200] [8801] [WARNING] Worker with pid 8802 was terminated due to signal 11
[2022-08-31 13:39:18 +0200] [8810] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8810
[2022-08-31 13:39:23 +0200] [8801] [WARNING] Worker with pid 8810 was terminated due to signal 11
[2022-08-31 13:39:23 +0200] [8814] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8814
```

Same happens with `python manage.py runserver` command.
I'm using a virtual environment with python 3.9

Comment: Did you set `DEBUG` to `True` to check if you receive additional information?

Comment: Yes, but it fails silently...

Answer (score 0):

Signal 11 (SIGSEGV, also known as segmentation violation) means that the program accessed a memory location that was not assigned to it.

That's usually a bug in a program. So if you're writing your own program, that's the most likely cause.

It can also commonly occur with some hardware malfunctions.